# Restoring views to their default state

Tags: views

Views module comes with a few default views. I have enabled and modified the frontpage view, but I'd like to go back to its default state that originally came with the module on a fresh install (without my changes). Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: D8+ question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/267512/7177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

1. Go to the views listing page (admin/structure/views).
2. In the **Operations** column of the view you want to reset, click the **Revert** operation.
3. Confirm by clicking the **Revert** button.

[image]