# Revert views missing. Any workarounds?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8 reverting views to their original (in the core, custom or contributed module) became difficult. Supposedly the module [config_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_update) would allow reverting a view, but that promises to be a more laborious than simply clicking a link like we were used to in Drupal 7.

I was wondering if it would be possible to make selected views read-only? That way administrators with Views UI permission would have no edit link forcing them to work with a duplicate.

Hints on how to accomplish this? Any other possible workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround without an additional module would be to copy and paste the content of the yaml file `views.view.[view-id].yml` you find in the module's /config/optional folder to *www.mysite.com/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import*.

Select the configuration type "View" and add the first line containing the UUID from the active configuration (switch to Export - Single item).

If you have to do this on a regular basis then the recommend way is to manage the configuration with Git, see this tutorial [Using Configuration Management and Git to Track Drupal 8 Configuration](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/using-configuration-management-and-git-drupal-8).