# media entity browser base view is missing

Tags: views, 8

What happened to the base view for Media Entity Browser?

Following this tutorial:

https://www.easternstandard.com/blog/2017/12/drupal-media-bundles-media-browser-cropping

I made all the changes since Media Entity is now in core, but I googled and could no mention of what happened to Media Entity Browser. Is it now in core too?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Media Entity Browser is still in contrib. If you are using core media then use the 2.x branch, see https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_browser. If this is only about the question in the title, see [Revert views missing. Any workarounds?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267512/revert-views-missing-any-workarounds) how to import a View from a module folder. If the View is missing you don't need to look for the UUID of the existing View.

Comment: +1 base view is back. My problem now is that file types is not appearing under admin/struture and admin/structure/file-types is throwing a page not found. Not sure if this is related to the media debacle.